# Backup fails when trying from Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, backup

I am trying to perform SQL server database backup to a shared location from Azure. It is failing with the below error:

> Backup failed for Server 'ingbtcpic7vw069'. 
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.3000.0+((SQL11_PCU_Main).121019-1325+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Backup+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Cannot open backup device
>   '\10.64.178.196\backupfolder\test11.bak'. Operating system error
>   1326(The user name or password is incorrect.).
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Can anyone help me in rectifying the issue?

Tried to do manual backup from GUI, it also failed.

Comment: Are you trying to backup an Azure SQL Database (PaaS) or a SQL Server database on an Azure VM (IaaS)?

Comment: Issue resolved.
SQL server services were running under local account, once changed to the Network account, issue resolved.

Comment: Please make this the answer of your question.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution.